# Manipulating Frame labels when legends are also there

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

I am plotting a few curves inside a frame with labels on three of its sides; left, right and bottom. I want legends to be places at the top. The problem which I am facing is that the top label occupies white space and I want it not to do so. In the code it is labeled as "I want this removed". Please guide me how can I remove the top label completely leaving no gap between frame and legends.

```
Plot[{Sin[h],Cos[h],Tan[h]},{h,5,10},
PlotStyle->{{GrayLevel[0],Dashing[None],Thickness[0.005]},
   {GrayLevel[0],Dashing[Tiny],Thickness[0.005]},
   {GrayLevel[0],Dashing[Small],Thickness[0.005]},
   {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[Medium],Thickness[0.005]}},
 Axes -> False,
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel->{{"Left", Rotate["Right",180 Degree]},{"Bottom","I want this removed"}},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[Automatic, {"sin", "cos", "tan"},
 LegendMarkerSize->{{45, 15}}],Top]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to put None instead of "Top" as follows:

```
Plot[{Sin[h], Cos[h], Tan[h]}, {h, 5, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{GrayLevel[0], Dashing[None], 
    Thickness[0.005]}, {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[Tiny], 
    Thickness[0.005]}, {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[Small], 
    Thickness[0.005]}, {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[Medium], 
    Thickness[0.005]}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Left", Rotate["Right", 180 Degree]}, {"Bottom", 
    None}},

 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[Automatic, {"sin", "cos", "tan"}, 
    LegendLayout -> "Row", LegendMarkerSize -> {{45, 15}}], {0.5, 
    1.002}]]
```

Then you get this:
[image]

If you need to have an additional label on top above the legends, use Column to combine them as here:

```
  Column[{
  Style["top", 10, "Times New Roman"],
  Plot[{Sin[h], Cos[h], Tan[h]}, {h, 5, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{GrayLevel[0], Dashing[None], 
      Thickness[0.005]}, {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[Tiny], 
      Thickness[0.005]}, {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[Small], 
      Thickness[0.005]}, {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[Medium], 
      Thickness[0.005]}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"Left", Rotate["Right", 180 Degree]}, {"Bottom", 
      None}},

   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[Automatic, {"sin", "cos", "tan"}, 
      LegendLayout -> "Row", LegendMarkerSize -> {{45, 15}}], {0.5, 
      1.001}], ImageSize -> 300
   ]
  }, Alignment -> Center]
```

which gives the following picture:
[image]

However, what I usually do is the following:

```
 Plot[{Sin[h], Cos[h], Tan[h]}, {h, 5, 10}, PlotRange -> {-3.5, 4.5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{GrayLevel[0], Dashing[None], 
    Thickness[0.005]}, {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[Tiny], 
    Thickness[0.005]}, {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[Small], 
    Thickness[0.005]}, {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[Medium], 
    Thickness[0.005]}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Left", Rotate["Right", 180 Degree]}, {"Bottom", 
    "Top"}},

 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[Automatic, {"sin", "cos", "tan"}, 
    LegendLayout -> "Column", LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {{45, 15}}], {0.85, 0.77}]]
```

yielding this:
[image]

Comment: This provides more flexibility and I think its a better way. Legends also look more beautiful this way. gratitude!

Answer (score 3):

You mean Like this? You can adjust `ImagePadding` on all 4 edges. It has the same layout for all other Frame related options

```
Plot[{Sin[h], Cos[h], Tan[h]}, {h, 5, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {{GrayLevel[0], Dashing[None], Thickness[0.005]},
   {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[Tiny], Thickness[0.005]}, {GrayLevel[0], 
    Dashing[Small], Thickness[0.005]}, {GrayLevel[0], Dashing[Medium],
     Thickness[0.005]}},
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Left", Rotate["Right", 180 Degree]}, {"Bottom", 
    "I want this removed"}},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[Automatic, {"sin", "cos", "tan"},
    LegendMarkerSize -> {{45, 15}}], Top], 
 ImagePadding -> {{30, 30}, {30, 2}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**before**

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Not quite I am afraid. The picture you Posted can be achieved by just removing the labels. As I mentioned in question three of them are required. Just top label is the problem. I know I can remove it by removing text from "" marks but it will then leave white space and legends will be at some distance. I want that distance to be removed keeping other three labels at their places.

Comment: Ok this makes sens now. Let me check what have you done.

Comment: yes you did the right thing. Webpage was not refreshed properly so I could not see other labels. I thought you removed all of them. This is what i wanted. Now i will learn more about ImagePadding. Rest is up to me thanks for your kind help.